# Is there a way to make a struct definition "private" to a single translation unit in C?

Tags: c, struct, static, linker

In C, you can use the `static` keyword to make global variables and functions private to the file in which they're defined. The compiler won't export these symbols, and thus the linker will not allow other modules to use these definitions.

However, I'm struggling to figure out how to restrict a struct definition such that it doesn't get added as an exported symbol that could accidentally be used by another module during the linking process. I would like to restrict this to the only file in which its defined.

Here are my attempts thus far which I've been struggling with.

```
// structure that is visible to other modules
struct PrivateStruct
{
    int hello;
    int there;
};

// this seems to throw an error
static struct PrivateStruct
{
    int hello;
    int there;
};

// i would ideally like to also wrap in the struct in a typedef, but this definitely doesn't work.
typedef static struct PrivateStruct
{
    int hello;
    int there;
} PrivateStruct;
```

Edit: I realize if I just define this struct in the .c file, others won't know about it. But won't it still technically be an exported symbol by the compiler? It would be nice to prevent this behavior.

Comment: Just define it inside of a single .c file.  Others won't see it.

Comment: @dbush Just updated my question with an edit. I'm thinking of going this route because it's probably simplest.

Comment: C does not *have* a global namespace.  Each translation unit has its own namespaces.  Variables and functions can have external linkage, meaning that the same entity can be accessed from different translation units, but that's not quite the same thing.  Type names always have no linkage.  They can be used only in the translation unit(s) where they are defined.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Agreed that it was a bad term. I will update question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I realize if I just define this struct in the .c file, others won't know about it. But won't it still technically be an exported symbol by the compiler?

No.  Whether you are talking about structure tags or `typedef`ed identifiers, these have no linkage.  Always.  There is no sense in which it would be reasonable to say that they are exported symbols.

This is among the reasons that header files are used in C.  If you want to use a structure type in one compilation unit that is compatible with a structure type in a different compilation unit then compatible structure type declarations must appear in *both*.  Putting the definition in a header makes it pretty easy to achieve that.

Comment: On the other hand, declaring a variable or function `static` *does not* necessarily imply that there will be no corresponding symbol in a corresponding binary file.  Such functions and variables have *internal* linkage, which is not the same as *no* linkage. Especially if you build shared libraries, you have a good chance of finding that the identifiers of those variables and functions do have corresponding symbols in the binary.

Comment: I guess I know just enough about linkers to have thought every "C global" item gets exported. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

yes..... you can use pointers to the structure, and to the outer world it is not deferrable.  Normally, that requires two header files, the first is the public one:

## header `mystruct.h`

This header is public, used by client code.

```
struct my_opaque;

/* we cannot use *p fields below, as the struct my_opaque is
 * incompletely defined here. */
void function_using(struct my_opaque *p, ...);
```

## header `mystructP.h`

This header is private, and includes the public header file to maintain the
API to the client code.

```
#include "mystruct.h" /* safety include (1) */
struct my_opaque {
     /* ... */
};
```

## implementation `mystruct.c`

In implementation code, we include the private header file, and so, we have full access to the structure fields.

```
#include "mystructP.h"

/* we have full definition, as we included mystructP.h */
void function_using(struct my_opaque *p,
       ...)
{
    ... /* we can use p->fields here */
}
```

(1) the safety `#include` allows to change the `struct my_opaque` and the API functions, and the compiler to blame you if you change something in the api to the caller modules, forcing you to recompile if you change something in that API.